# Could not load file or assembly TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=1.9.0.77

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

I am trying out BDD in Visual Studio 2013.  I have started a fresh new blank project.  I have written the feature file and steps definition.  I added SpecFlow using NugGet packages.  It installed SpecFlow version 2.1.0
When I build the solution it is looking for SpecFlow version 1.9.0.77

When I searched for SpecFlow in NugGet packages only 1 was listed.  I installed it and i believe it was the latest version  2.1.0
Why is the solution looking for an older version of 1.9.0.77 ?
If the resolution is to install 1.9.0.77 how do i install it and I how i find this version in NugGet?

The full error trace is:

```
Custom tool error: Generation error: Could not load file or assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=1.9.0.77, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. E:\RL Fusion\projects\BDD\C# BDD\youtubetutorial2\specflowfirst\SpecflowFirst\SpecflowFirst\Features\GoogleSearch.feature   2   2   SpecflowFirst
```

Thanks, Riaz

The imports are:

```
using Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.Bindings;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist;
```

Comment: I think I have worked it out.  key in the command Install-Package SpecFlow -Version 1.9.0 in the NugGet Manager Console

Comment: I uninstalled SpecFlow 2.1.0 I used the NugGet Manager console to intsall 1.9.0 and now when I build the solution it is still complaining it cannot find 1.9.0.77

Comment: It is because the package SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic is dependent on SpecFlow 2.1.0  Is SpecFlow 2.1.0 not supported in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I am going to install Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Please post all your packages in the package.config of your test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit does only work with SpecFlow 1.9.0. It claims that it work with versions after 1.9, but this is not true, because we changed the plugin- interface in SpecFlow. 
Did you wanted to use it, because of the ability to test against multiple browser with only one scenario?

If so, have a look at this example https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumWebTest which uses the SpecFlow+Runner as test runnner.
If you follow that, you have the same functionality and you can use the latest version of SpecFlow.

---

Full Disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+.

Comment: Thank you for the example to follow.